# Can I pay someone to put a bounty on my question?

Tags: discussion

I like getting attention for the questions I ask. I enjoy answering peoples questions, but personally, a lot of that motivation comes to get "monopoly money" that I can use to put bounties on my own questions.

Is it explicitly against the rules to pay someone to put a bounty on my question?

Comment: I mean, no one can tell you what to do with *your* money, but it seems a bit of a waste...

Comment: Are you asking if you can pay someone with actual money, not SE Rep?

Comment: Well, before you pay any money, try bopping into the chat and see if a. anyone can answer or b. anyone is willing to put a small bounty on it. Also, keep in mind there's always a chance bounties go unanswered, so your money could effectively be lost.

Comment: Sure. How much are your willing to pay? ;-)

Comment: from mother meta:  [181153](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181153/), [229225](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229225/), [148785](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148785/), [25615](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615/), [243404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243404/), etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea of involving real money in SE activity has been discussed a few times on meta sites (e.g. [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181153/), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229225/), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148785/), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615/), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243404/) as posted by [AccidentalFourierTransform](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/84967/accidentalfouriertransform) in a comment), and while there seems to be broad agreement that it would be a bad idea, I don't know of any rule that explicitly and directly forbids it. Assuming such a rule doesn't exist, I think part of the reason it doesn't exist is that people recognize it'd be impossible to enforce. The moderators and SE staff don't generally know (or care) what you do outside of the network.

Personally, I think if you offer anything more than a trivial amount of real money for bounties, it could easily lead to a situation where people are putting bounties on questions that don't deserve them and giving you an excessive share of the attention that comes to featured questions. That would be bad for the site. So I'd suggest that you not do it. But that's just me, speaking unofficially, that's not an outright rule as far as I know.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? Surely David is just stating the blindingly obvious? Perhaps the downvoter would like to post a comment explaining their reasoning.